# Using VBA to open a tab delimited .txt file to save to .xlsx format

Tags: vba, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to use VBA in Excel to automate turning a .txt file (tab delimited) into a .xlsx file instead.  Here's what I have:

```
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(folder + file, , , 1)
If Right(file, 3) = "txt" Or Right(file, 3) = "xls" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 4) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 5) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
WB.Close
```

This is just a snip of code, of course, and the first part of the code is the most relavant, I think.  I've only started checking the transformed .txt files, as they are 10% he size they should be after saving.  Turns out, the twenty columns are smushed into three, and all spaces and tabs have been removed.  Not sure what is going on, as I don't use VBA very often.

I'm thinking the key is here:

```
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(folder + file, , , 1)
```

The 1 at the end signifies tab delimited.  Not sure what it will do for the .xls files it also opens, but I'll worry about that next.

Thanks for any pointers you can give.

---

Edit.

I changed the code around to treat .txt and .xls differently, as I should have done in the first place.  Here is the current code:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
'Dim WBS As Workbooks

If Right(file, 3) = "txt" Then
    Set WB = Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=folder + file, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB(1).SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 4) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    WB.Close
ElseIf Right(file, 3) = "xls" Then
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(folder + file)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 4) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    WB.Close
Else
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(folder + file)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 5) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    WB.Close
End If
```

Comment: Did you try `Workbooks.OpenText`?  That seems to work for me.  Try `Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\filenameandpath", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True`

Comment: That's an excellent start, but then I don't see how to save it as an xlsx afterward.  There's no built in save functionality that I can see for Workbooks (plural), just for Workbook (singular).

Comment: Excel's method call to a single workbook *is* plural `Workbooks`.  It should work okay.

Comment: I only see you opening 1 workbook so the saveas method should work for you.   Dim wb As Workbook
wb.SaveAs "fileNameHere", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Comment: You're already using `Workbooks` to open your file.  Just use `Set WB = Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=...` and you'll have your (one) workbook open.  To save, you can use what you're using now or you can save it using the `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` property.

Comment: Updated the code a bit.  Also tried using .SaveAs with a Workbooks object; didn't work as it couldn't find the method.  WB is a Workbook object while WBS is a Workbooks object.

Comment: I thought I might add some clarification.  When you use `Excel.Workbooks` you're referencing a kind of collection.  Say you have a workbook called `Test.xlsx` open.  You can reference it by using `Excel.Workbooks("Test.xlsx")`.  Or, you can iterate over your workbooks using `For ... Each` or select one by the index `Excel.Workbooks(1)`, or open one `Excel.Workbooks.Open` or `Excel.Workbooks.OpenText`.  or add a new one `Excel.Workbooks.Add`.  It's a fairly versatile way of doing this.  Don't get distracted because it is plural, you aren't retrieving the whole collection, just a single book.

Comment: Ok, resolved this with WBS(1).SaveAs.  Now getting error with the OpenText: Object variable or With block variable not set.  I'm willing to bet I'm missing something small and simple with this one.

Comment: Look at my answer below.  How are you diming WBS?  Depending on that, you're either only saving a single sheet of the workbook (which might be fine, but I suspect it isn't doing what you think it is doing) or you're grabbing the workbooks collection.  You get the error that you are encountering when you try to perform an action on an object that is set to nothing.  Which would happen if you try to use the .OpenText method of the workbook object, because that isn't a method of the workbook object, it's a method of the workbooks object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this again with your own code down here where I have more room.  Try the following and read my comments above.  I think you'll find it works:

```
'I'm adding this line.  I'm assuming you have it in your code, but just to be certain...
Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
'This line opens your tab delimeted text file.
Set WB = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=folder + file, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
If Right(file, 3) = "txt" Or Right(file, 3) = "xls" Then
    'This section turns off alerts, saves the workbook opened in the previous step as xlsx and turns alerts back on.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 4) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
    'Again, this section saves the workbook opened in the previous step as xlsx.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 5) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
WB.Close
```

I'm also debating whether or not you really need that If statement.  It looks like you're doing the exact same thing and naming the workbook using the same convention.  You might not need it.  I left it because you didn't ask about it specifically.  You could skip it and just save the workbook I think.

Edit:  You need the If statement to pick the method you use to open your workbook...

```
'I'm adding this line.  I'm assuming you have it in your code, but just to be certain...
Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
If Right(file, 3) = "txt" then
    'This line opens your tab delimeted text file.
    Set WB = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=folder + file, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
Else
    'This line opens your xls and xlsx books
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(folder + file) 'no additional parameters should be needed
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WB.SaveAs filename:=folder + milestone + "_" + loadtype + "_" + Left(file, Len(file) - 4) + "_" + metricDate + "_.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
WB.Close
```

If you're iterating over a number of these input workbooks you may want to do

```
Set WB = Nothing
```

just to be safe.

Edit:  I'll let my shame hang out up there... the `OpenText` method does not return an object, so you'll have to set the `WB` object using `Set WB = Workbooks(file)` after you've opened it assuming `file` is the full filename including extension.  My bad on that one.

Comment: The input files can be .txt, .xls, or .xlsx.  I need to parse out the filename to add a prefix before the file extension.  It will always be saved as a .xlsx.  This is why I have the If, and why I need to open in more than one way.

Comment: AH!  I see.  You need the if statement before you open the workbook then.  Look at the saving part.  It doesn't change.  And it won't once you have the workbook open.  What you need is to look at the end of the file name and set up an if statement to open `.txt` using workbooks.OpenText and `.xls` or `.xlsx` using `Workbooks.Open`.   I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Updated code up top, below the Edit line.  Included Dim statement.  Getting compile error with your line; likely a combination of my Dim and your code.  (Expected: end of statement - Filename highlighted)

Comment: Which line?  You might have an extra comma in there or something.  Evetything I see from your most recent update looks good.  The Expected end of statement is just telling you that something is wrong with the syntax of that line.  You have a parameter typed incorrectly or something.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a compile error after adding the close paren at the end of the Workbooks.OpenText statement.  Expected Function or Variable, with .OpenText highlighted.  Get the previously mentioned error when removing the parens.  Otherwise looking good.  Still need the larger if, as need to strip .xls or .xlsx off and they have different lengths.

Comment: It highlights Filename in Set WB = Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=...  I tried concating the folder and file vars elsewhere in case that was it, but same error.

Comment: Found it.  OpenText doesn't return an object, so Set doesn't work here.

Comment: once you open the workbook/textfile you can reference it from the workbooks object IE:  set WB = Application.Workbooks("Name of book aka text file")

Comment: Yep.  Used Set WB = ActiveWorkbook.  The output matches what I would get if I did it manually, though the file is about 8 MB larger.  not sure why.  But otherwise looks good.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You are correct.  In that case, try this:  Just do `Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=folder + file, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True` on one line and then on the next, assuming `file` is the full filename of your workbook (example: "test.txt") then on the line following do `Set WB = Workbooks(file)` and that should set your workbook object to the opened file.

Comment: Someone beat me to it, but it appears you have it sorted now and I've edited the anser above.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this.  Everything looks good, except for the txt to xlsx dropping the leading zeros.  The files have a variable number of columns, so this should be fun to fix.

Comment: @user3264015 Format the cells of the worksheet as next... I think you could do WB.Worksheets(1).Cells.numberformat = "@" and you should be able to keep the leading 0's.  I have to battle that all the time.  I think you can even set up a custom format where you wind up keeping the leading 0's if you need to still be able to do calculations on them.

Comment: Ok, my method didn't work.  Formatting after opening will change to text, but will already have lost leading zeros.  Saw that trying to open directly in Excel without specifing to make all columns as text.

Comment: Never mind.  Using the FieldInfor for 90 columns did work.  Ugly, but it worked.

Comment: Try adding FieldInfo to your OpenText statement. Use "1" as the second index of the array to specify "general format" and "2" to specify "text" format. You will need one Array for each column, and the column of your input will be specified using the first index of the array. So, if you have 5 columns in your input and you want them all to be text to retain leading 0's except for the last column which you'd like formatted as general use `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 1))`

Comment: All you need is a two dimensional array with your column number in the first element and your type in the second.  If you want text for each column just do `Dim ArgArray(0 to 89, 0 to 1)` and then use a `for counter = 0 to 89` loop to put 1 to 90 in `ArgArray(counter, 0)` and 2 in `ArgArray(counter, 1)`.  Then use that as your argument:  `FieldInfo:=ArgArray` and that should get you what you want.