# vba Excel 2003 format to Excel 2007 format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I changed the file Excel 2003 xls format to Excel 2007 xlsx format.
I was able to change, but there are some files that I cannot open.
When I open specific file. It says "excel removed part /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part. (drawing shape)"

I looked into other threads, but couldn't find solutions.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22617966/1009225) and edited as follows.

```
Sub fileConv(filepath As String)
Dim ext
ext = ".xls"

Dim WB As New Excel.Workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath + ext)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WB.SaveAs Filename:=filepath + ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
WB.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks quite ok, however, this seems to be an issue with Excel and certain drawings, such as pictures in comments, as a quick Google search reveals. Do you have complex drawings in your files?

Comment: MP24 thank you for reply.drawings like pictures jpeg with arrows and rectangles and finally grouped.  I also have some files with macros which i changed into xlsm, too, have same problem. Even I removed macros the problem persists.